# React Ag grid expandAll in enterprise

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have data in four levels of grouping and when using expandAll feature in ag grid, how can I set it to expand till level 2? I don't want the user to see data expanded till 4 levels but I want to give expandAll functionality till level 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method in the API to do that but you can write your own custom method to expand at certain level easily using the `RowNode` info the grid API give you

```js
const expand = (upToLevel) => () => {
  gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level < upToLevel) {
      node.expanded = true;
    } else {
      node.expanded = false;
    }
  });
  gridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
};
```

#### Usage

```
<button onClick={expand(1)}>Expand lvl1</button>
<button onClick={expand(2)}>Expand lvl2</button>
<button onClick={expand(3)}>Expand lvl3</button>
```

#### Live Example

[image: Edit AgGrid Expand Group To Lvl]